# If statement not running: any ideas?

Tags: java, if-statement

I am trying to compare the third number to the last number and the fourth number to the fifth number. The if statement isn't running at all any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;

class Problem2{

      public static void main (String[] args){

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number between 100000 and 999996: ");
        int m = s.nextInt();
        if(m < 100000 || m > 999996){
           System.out.println("Out of range!");
        }
        else{
         String j = Integer.toString(m);
         for(int i=2;i<6,i++){
            System.out.println(j.charAt(i));
            if(j.charAt(i) == (j.charAt(i)+3)&& (j.charAt(i)+1) == (j.charAt(i)+2)){
               System.out.println("Works!");
            }


         }

      }
   }  

}
```

Comment: Define 'not running'.

Comment: Also, which if statement

Comment: you have syntax issues and I even change what answers told you, you still have issues ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are incrementing the *value*, not the *index* of the character.

Change this:

```
if (j.charAt(i) == (j.charAt(i)+3)&& (j.charAt(i)+1) == (j.charAt(i)+2))
```

To this:

```
if (j.charAt(i) == j.charAt(i+3) && j.charAt(i+1) == j.charAt(i+2)) 
// increment indexes      --^              --^              --^
```

Answer (score 3):

Move the additions inside of the `charAt()` calls.

```
if(j.charAt(i) == (j.charAt(i+3))&& (j.charAt(i+1)) == (j.charAt(i+2)))
```